# How to host an application in facebook

Tags: php, facebook

I have hosted my application in the server. Can anyone explain the steps clearly to host the app in the facebook and to post the ouput image in the fb news feed using php.

Thanks,
Lokesh

Comment: This is way too vague to answer - you should probably start here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs

Answer (score 4):

Give these two blog posts a try, the explain how to host a facebook application on openshift:
https://www.openshift.com/blogs/developing-facebook-applications-on-openshift-getting-set-up
https://www.openshift.com/blogs/developing-facebook-applications-on-openshift-launch-your-app

Answer (score 2):

You don't "host" applications in facebook, you host them on a server and tell facebook the address to which it should post when a user wants to access the app.

It's all configured in the App Settings page in the developers app.
As @Igy said, your questions is too vague to answer, you need to research yourself first, try various things, and come back with more specific questions.

To get started try the [Apps on Faceook.com](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/) tutorial.
It covers most of the basic things you'll need to know, including the App Settings page in the developers app.

Good luck.